# what やる after command form means?

Tags: grammar

I received the following message:

> 無理しないでやるよね。

What function やる performs here?

Also could I say just:

> 無理しないでよね

Can I put the particles like that after a command/request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that 無理しないで is not command but just modifying やる, which is the main verb. So the sentence means "You will do it without pushing yourself, won't you?".

Comment: Ohhh, like バスで行く right?

Comment: Do you have other example like: verb+で+verb?

Comment: In Japanese grammar, is しないで actually considered to be modifying やる? I'd have though that 理由しない and やるよね were to be considered independent clauses joined with the て形.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Try thinking of ないで as a single unit.

Comment: @G-Cam I'm not sure if しないで is a te form to begin with. But anyway it seems just a matter of interpretation or even rhetoric to me.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira I don't know other examples that take that form and I'm not sure if しない is a verb to begin with.

Comment: What I had in mind was 無理しない(to not force oneself) + で ( do something by a given way) + やる (to do) = "Do something in a way that does not force oneself too much"... because if I was to parse 無理しないで + やる, I would think of 無理しないで  as a command form

Comment: Whether it's interpreted as command or conjunctive doesn't have to do with how you parse 無理しないで because the command use derives from 無理しない＋で＋くれ.

Comment: @user4092 I may be thinking way too much into it, but I just wanna make sense of the logic behind this structure, cuz that way I will learn better.
Let's say a kid ask his mom if he can do "something" in the kitchen (which is full with the food for the lunch), could the mom say 「何も食べないですれば、いいよ」? Sorry for the trouble in asking the same thing too much

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Not at all. As for what you're asking about, it's yes (though it should be 何も食べないでするなら…). I don't really think it's worth analyzing deeply because this form is exceptional.